# Convert UTC Date and Time to local Date and Time using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my mongo date is getting stored as `2020-10-01T05:32:41.379Z`. I am trying to convert to my local time which is 5:30 hrs after the UTC time.
I tried using `moment(new Date(update.planned_date)).zone("+0530").toDate())`. But i am still getting the same time `2020-10-01T05:32:41.379Z`.
My expected output is `2020-10-01T11:02:41.379Z` which is 5:30 after the UTC time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `local()` from momentjs to get the local time equivalent of the UTC

```js
const date = moment
  .utc("2020-10-01T05:32:41.379Z", "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")
  .local()
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The above approach gave me in this format 2020-10-01T11:02:41+05:30. I want in proper Z forma i.e. 2020-10-01T11:02:41.379Z